# Scroll appears on a hover item

Tags: css, scroll, web, hover, flexbox

i have a little problem with my navigation and :hover class on . http://prntscr.com/dp349n

Here's a [link](https://videotest22.000webhostapp.com/) to a website. Problem appears when you hover on the menu (each list).

I want the underline/2px border of a element on that little white line.

Comment: Could you let me know what is not working with the answer a gave, so I will be able to adjust and you to accept?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do this change:

**First Way:** On your style.css modify this code:

```
body .group-wrapper .container nav.navigation ul li a:hover {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #222;
}
```

to this:

```
body .group-wrapper .container nav.navigation ul li a:hover {
    border-bottom: 0px solid #222;
}
```

**Second Way:** Just add this code in style.css at last

```
body .group-wrapper .container nav.navigation ul li a:hover {
    border-bottom: 0px !important;
}
```